# How do I manage this android database

Tags: android, sql, database

So how di I manage a Android database which isn't even located in the assets folder. I followed this tutorial, and it's great, but what if I want to delete and add information to tables manually?
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Database/Createdeleteupdate.htm

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you trying to do and when? Prior to building your app or dynamically when the app is running?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use other software to modify you Database simply by opening the assets file with that software.

Here is [SQLite Expert](http://www.sqliteexpert.com/) that is recommended for modifying your Database

Comment: FinalDark, I do have similar programs, but the database being generated by the code is NOT located in the assets folder.

Comment: If that so you can use the SQLite Manager for Andriod in the apps store but i did not try it.  

Here is the link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xuecs.sqlitemanager